# JavaScript ES6 curly braces in arguments to old-style JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using Vue/VueX inside a WebView, and while testing on an emulator with Android 5.0.2 which only has Chrome 30 support, I noticed that the page does not load.

I traced it down to the missing ES6 support, and decided to "downgrade" the page to the old-style JavaScript.

I'm having some issues with the following syntax

```
actions: {
  push_back_button       ({ commit }, callback)       { commit('push_back_button', callback)          },
  pop_back_button        ({ commit })                 { commit('pop_back_button')                     },
  ...
```

which I tried to translate to

```
actions: {
  push_back_button:       function (commit, callback)       { commit('push_back_button', callback)          },
  pop_back_button:        function (commit)                 { commit('pop_back_button')                     },
  ...
```

But I'm getting a message during load that `Uncaught TypeError: commit is not a function`.

How would I do this properly? I am not using any stuff like webpack, this runs in the Browser/WebView as-is and the ES6 version of the page works fine on devices which support it.

Comment: You can use Babel REPL for traspiling the code back to ES5 https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBA9hC8EG8BQBIEBjALgSygOwGcAuRVCciABwFcCALAfQCMMBrZ6zTfACgQnRQAtkOyYIAXwA0AkABs5LdKwCUiAcNGYeAchr1mbDl3w6Z6eYrZrpZCpSiVDy49zx8NIsZLX9BX7T1HZ3YmTjcdG1QJJAkgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=

Comment: Wow, thanks @adiga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push_back_button` and `pop_back_button` expects first parameter to be an object.

`({ commit })` deconstructs object parameter to get it's property `commit`

```
actions: {
  push_back_button:       function (object, callback)       { object.commit('push_back_button', callback)          },
  pop_back_button:        function (object)                 { object.commit('pop_back_button')                     },
}
```

```js
function fn(parent) {
 console.log("called from", parent);
}

function es5_fn(object) {
 object.fn("es5_fn");
}

function es6_fn({fn}) {
 fn("es6_fn");
}

es5_fn({fn});
es6_fn({fn});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. You wouldn't have a book recommendation for me on this topic, wouldn't you? I have no clue about the new features of Javascript, even though I use the old style on a daily basis.

Comment: @DanielF sorry but books recommendations are prohibited on SO :( But you can start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla

Comment: @DanielF https://exploringjs.com/es6/ and https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/es6%20&%20beyond/README.md#you-dont-know-js-es6--beyond and http://es6-features.org/

Answer (score 1):

That's because `({commit})` is translated by `(item)` where `item` is an object containing at least `commit`.

Can you try this:

```
actions: {
  push_back_button:       function (item, callback)       { item.commit('push_back_button', callback)          },
  pop_back_button:        function (item)                 { item.commit('pop_back_button')                     },
  ...
```